# VBA Api request in Excel, with values from cells using vba-json

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

I'm currently working on an excel table that reads various API's and processes the results.

I'm trying to adapt an api request for this table, but unfortunately I can't do it.
I'm assuming this good working code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next


    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price", False
    On Error Resume Next
    http.Send
    On Error GoTo error
    Set json = ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
    i = 10

    For Each Item In json
        If Item("symbol") = Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value And Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = Item("price")
     
            i = i + 1
        End If
   
    Next


    Exit Sub
    error:
End Sub
```

CELL A1 says: ETHBTC and I get the corresponding value in J1

Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work and I don't understand why:

```
Sub GetVolume()
    On Error Resume Next
    'List of all symbols
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://api.coincap.io/v2/candles", False
    On Error Resume Next
    http.Send
    Set json = ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
    i = 10
    For Each Item In json("data")
        If Item("exchange") = Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value And Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
 
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = Item("volume")

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    Exit Sub
error:
End Sub
```

In this case, the content of cell A1 looks like this:

binance&interval=m5&baseId=monero&quoteId=bitcoin&start=1649894400000&end=1649898000000

The request for this looks like this:

https://api.coincap.io/v2/candles?exchange=poloniex&interval=h1&baseId=ethereum&quoteId=bitcoin&start=1649894400000&end=1649898000000

I would be very grateful for a tip

I've tried different combinations, but get no answer

Answer (score 0):

**"https://api.coincap.io/v2/candles"** `HTTPRequest.responseText`:

> "{"error":"missing quote","timestamp":1672666785053}"

The code is returning an **missing quote** error, caused by missing query parameters.

[CoinCap Docs](https://docs.coincap.io/) has a query builder that you can use.  Start with a working query and than start modifying parameters until it fits your specifications.

---

I recommend creating a function to handle returning the json data. This simplifies development by making it easier to test the code.

```
Function QueryCoinCap(URL As String) As Object
    On Error GoTo QueryCoinCap_Error
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send

        Set QueryCoinCap = ParseJson(.ResponseText)
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

QueryCoinCap_Error:
    Rem CoinCap was unable to process the request
    Rem to simplify the error handle I'll create a Scripting.Dictionary and ADD A CUSTOM ERROR TO IT
    Rem This allows us to treat all errors in the same way
    Dim Dictionary As Object
    Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dictionary("error") = "CoinCap was unable to process the request"
    Set QueryCoinCap = Dictionary
End Function

Sub WorkingExampleQueryCoinCap()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets"
    
    Dim JsonDictionary As Object
    Set JsonDictionary = QueryCoinCap(URL)
    
    If JsonDictionary.Exists("error") Then
        Debug.Print JsonDictionary("error")
    Else
        Stop
        Rem Do Something
    End If
End Sub


Sub ErrorExampleQueryCoinCap()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/candles"
    
    Dim JsonDictionary As Object
    Set JsonDictionary = QueryCoinCap(URL)
    
    If JsonDictionary.Exists("error") Then
        Debug.Print JsonDictionary("error")
    Else
        Rem Do Something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The values for the request, such as baseId and quoteId, should actually be taken from cell A1. The idea is that I can make multiple requests with different variable values.